# Is there a word or collocation for an unwanted person?

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

I'm looking for a word or collocation we use in British English when we want to refer to someone who's interested in you, attracted to you, but whose advances at you are not welcome. Thank you! :)

Comment: Thank you guys, "bothersome admirer" will suit my situation perfectly! But can I say "bothersome crush" too? Or "crush" can't be used to refer to a person just the feeling?

Comment: Saying that "X is my crush" would usually imply that you are attracted to X, rather than the other way round. So "bothersome crush" would be a contradiction.

Comment: @Györgyi Also in British usage 'a crush' is the feeling you experience towards a person rather than the person them self. eh 'Anne has a huge crush on Colin'. The American usage of 'crush' being the person is understood though, and may be increasing in use here.

Comment: You could call him a *creep* and a *weirdo*, among friends and acquaintances. Cue [Radiohead](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZiNtbgm9oM) song

Answer (score 2):

An ***unwelcome admirer/suitor***:

> - someone whose personal requests and attentions (regarding a possible casual or stable relationship) are not appreciated.

Comment: +1 for ***unwelcome admirer***, but I think it's fair to say ***unwelcome suitor*** was [never very common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unwelcome+admirer%2Cunwelcome+suitor&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunwelcome%20admirer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunwelcome%20suitor%3B%2Cc0), and would be a bit "affected" in most conversational contexts today.

Comment: I agree, I mentioned "suitor"  in reference to a possible stable relationship not knowing what OP is actually looking for.

Comment: I expect there will be various slang terms with (approximately) the same meaning - but none came to mind for me, and ***unwelcome admirer*** has become a pretty standard expression even among people who'd be highly unlikely to use the word ***admirer*** in the sense of ***suitor*** in any other context. In short, to my mind it's probably the only game in town unless we're going to consider limited-currency slang expressions.

Answer (score 1):

"Stalker" would be my first response but perhaps that's too harsh since there's a more dangerous connotation to that word. Some less harsh possibilities:

- bothersome admirer
- nonreciprocal crush
- non-fancied
- unfancy